Unity for Android - signing application using secret keystore manager
We’re dynamically fetching keystore file with secrets before opening the Unity project and storing them in a cache (~/devcache/blahblah/). The path to the keystore and its passwords is available once the project is generated and stored in /Assets/Plugins/Android/gradleTemplate.properties.
We can’t use Unity’s Keystore Manager (no manual clicks) in Project Settings > Publishing Settings:

as on every machine the directory of the keystore may be different (we know the path and store it in gradleTemplate.properties but we can't hardcode it in unity in this tick.
I added a custom mainTemplate.gradle with this signing config:
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(project.DYNAMIC_KEYSTORE_PATH)
        storePassword project.DYNAMIC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias project.DYNAMIC_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword project.DYNAMIC_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
}

But Unity seems to override (ignore?) these settings, and the APK is signed with the debug keystore. Verification using apksigner shows:
apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs android.apk
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v3.1 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3.1): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug

How can I make Unity use these dynamic variables for signing during the build?
